# AD keeps local accounts from timing out?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Currently, our customer requirements say that after 60 days, the local accounts on our devices are supposed to be locked. When AD is being implemented, the local accounts are not being used (everyone authenticates through the AD server). The other day, the AD server went down, and nobody could login to to our servers because all the local accounts had been timed out and locked. Is there any way to have AD keep the local accounts active so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Your problem is odd. Even if you can't contact the AD, you should have cached credentials allowing you to log in. What specifically happened?

Comment: Why do you only have 1 domain controller? Build another for redundancy <easyButton>

Comment: We have several LDAP servers. The issue is that several of our sites are located outside of the US, and for physical security reasons, those sites do not have a local LDAP server. At times of high congestion, those sights have very intermittent connection to the LDAP servers and sometimes become disconnected from them. TLDR: not all local sites have LDAP servers and become completely inaccessible certain times of the day due this fact.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a security policy set to not cache accounts and one that disables the local accounts. If its already been decided that caching accounts is risky, then you have exactly the behavior expected.  The only solution is to enable caching for some period of time.

Comment: Is there a way to configure certain accounts to be cached all of the time on certain devices (like the sysadmin accounts)? I am not an AD expert. Local accounts are not explicitly disabled. The pam.d configurations lock a local account after 60 days if it is not used. Each server has a local account (kept under lock and key by the admin) that is a service account only, but it is not used when LDAP is up (all users log in with their credentials). The only way to keep these local accounts unlocked is to go login to them every 60 days which is not salable solution for the # of servers we have.

Comment: Are you saying your are not using active directory?

Comment: There is an AD server that is being used. When the AD server goes down or a device cannot connect to it, if the accounts are not cached on all of the local machines, then the local accounts are used. The issue is that the  local accounts lock after 60 days of inactivity. The AD server is up 99.995% of the time so the local accounts are never used except for that .005% of the time when there is an outage. I encountered a situation where, when the local accounts were needed, they were locked. Without someone around who has the credentials for the local account, a much longer outage occurred.

Comment: I am investigating caching local accounts. This is new to me. My issue with caching accounts is that if I do not log into that server, my account is not cached on that server. There are thousands of servers on our network located at sites around the world, so short of logging into them before the cache expires every time, it does not seem like a viable solution. Unless I can somehow in AD check to have my account cached on all of the servers, all of the time.

Comment: Then what does Pam.d have to do with it?  There certainly isn't a Pam.d on the clients and ldap is only a small part of an AD login.

Comment: If the server cannot reach the LDAP server, it falls back onto local which runs through pam.d. Unless I am mistaken about how the local accounts are used if the server cannot reach the LDAP server.

Comment: So this is not a windows box?

Comment: For this particular instance, yes. The client machines that could not be reached were Linux machines. Without the ability to reach the AD server, and only one emergency local account (which the customer requires locks after 60 days, and cannot be used when LDAP is up), the clients basically are brick'ed. I am trying to find a solution to this problem (the original question). Can I create the "local account" on the AD server and somehow push it to login or re-new the 60 day limit on the clients every 60 days? Or is there an easier approach to this?

Comment: No I suspect not., you're stuck with the limitations of Linux using ldap instead of AD on windows.  You should edit your question though to reflect that this has nothing to do with windows but with LINUX authentication- you are likely to attract someone with Linux knowledge since that's where the problem lies.